# Moving MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've built a WPF app, which completely works now. However, to clean it up a bit I wish to move my `MainWindow.xaml` to the view folder I've created. After I've done this the application won't run and it gives me an *"Unknown build error"* which doesn't give any info on how to fix it...
What should I change in my `MainWindow.xaml` to let the app work properly again?

I've already changed

```
<Window x:Class="projectname.MainWindow">
```

to

```
<Window x:Class="projectname.view.MainWindow">
```

Should I change other stuff as well?

Comment: Show your codebehind cs file as well, including that file's namespace.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You don't need to update class name in xaml file unless you have changed the namespace of your class.
Most likely you haven't updated **`StartupUri`** for **`App.xaml`**. Change it to:

```
StartupUri="view/MainWindow.xaml"
```

from

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
```

Comment: Happens sometimes that we miss so obvious things. Glad it worked for you finally.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The [answer of @Rohit Vats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25472787/5259296) is quite good!

However there's a good point to remember: you have to change all the **absolute paths** (in XAML) to your resources, prepending them by a `/` in order to indicate that these paths are **relative** to the `root directory`.

---

Example:

From `<Image Source="Assets/Loading.gif">`

To `<Image Source="/Assets/Loading.gif">` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this myself. Here's what I did:

1. Move your `MainWindow.xaml` to your new folder. In my case it was /Views.
2. I like to name all my classes with their namespaces reflecting their folder. So my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` namespace went from `ProjectNamespace` to `ProjectNamespace.Views`
3. In my `MainWindow.xaml`, I needed to change `x:Class` from `ProjectName.MainWindow` to `ProjectName.Views.MainWindow`.
4. In your App.xaml, change the `StartupUri` to reflect the folder. I went from `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` to "StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml"`

Doing this allowed me to compile and run my app.